# Why am I not seeing any kind of extracted data when I run this code

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, etl

I am trying to run this code in idle 3.10.6 and I am not seeing any kind of data that should be extracted from Indeed. All this data should be in the output when I run it but it isnt. Below is the input statement

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def extract(page):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko"}
    url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&l=United+States&sc=0kf%3Ajt%28internship%29%3B&vjk=a2f49853f01db3cc={page}"
    r = requests.get(url,headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find ("a").text.strip()
        company = item.find("span", class_="company").text.strip()
        try:
            salary = item.find("span", class_ = "salarytext").text.strip()
        finally:
            salary =  ""
        summary = item.find("div",{"class":"summary"}).text.strip().replace("\n","")

        job = {
            "title":title,
            "company":company,
            'salary':salary,
            "summary":summary
        }
        joblist.append(job)

joblist = []

for i in range(0,40,10):
    print(f'Getting page, {i}')
    c = extract(10)
    transform(c)

df = pd.DataFrame(joblist)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('jobs.csv')
```

Here is the output I get

```
Getting page, 0
Getting page, 10
Getting page, 20
Getting page, 30
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Why is this going on and what should I do to get that extracted data from indeed? What I am trying to get is the jobtitle,company,salary, and summary information. Any help would be greatly apprieciated.

Comment: The class `jobsearch-SerpJobCard` doesn't exist in the HTML source, they're added dynamically by JavaScript.

Comment: Why thank you for the help, however what should I do to replace that then or in other words, what should I do?

Comment: See the question I linked to at the top.